# Openvpn unrecognized option tls-version-min

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I am trying to connect to my university's VPN network using the provided ovpn configuration file. However, I get the following error message:

```
Options error: Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in kit.ovpn:9: tls-version-min (2.3.2)
```

The configuration file "kit.ovpn" contains the following line 9:

```
tls-version-min 1.2
```

What is the probleme here and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You are running an old version of `openvpn`, namely `v 2.3.2`, which does not support that option.
Make sure you have at least version `2.3.6` installed.

I assume that you do are still running `14.04 LTS` and will have to do the release upgrade via `do-release-upgrade` and the upgrade the package or manually install `openvpn` from source.